# Injecting FormControlDirective says it can't find unspecified name

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor, angular16, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I'm injecting `FormControlDirective` in my CVA like so:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-boolean-select',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
    template: '<input [formControl]="formControl"/>',
})
export class BooleanSelectWithTooltipComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    readonly #directive = inject(FormControlDirective, {self: true})
    protected readonly formControl = this.#directive.control as FormControl<boolean | null>

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.#directive.valueAccessor = this
    }
```

Since I'm getting the containing control, I can't use the `providers` array and thus I'm assigning the `valueAccessor` directly. However, that results in a slew of errors in the console saying both of these:

> NG01203: No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly here?